# remove part of string after pattern

Tags: r

I'm working with ; separated strings like

```
a="My name is Laura;My name is Martin;My name is Carl;"
```

I want to remove the part after name, and have this as result:

```
a="My name;My name;My name;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gsub`:

```r
gsub("(?<=name)[^;]*", "", a, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "My name;My name;My name;"
```

Alternatively, we can use `gregexpr` and `` `regmatches<-` `` for this:

```r
gre <- gregexpr("(?<=name)[^;]*", a, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(a, gre)
# [[1]]
# [1] " is Laura"  " is Martin" " is Carl"  
regmatches(a, gre) <- ""
a
# [1] "My name;My name;My name;"
```

Walk-through:

- `(?<=name)` is a *lookbehind* regex that does not "consume" the `name` string, just uses it as a starting-point; this is a Perl extension, ergo `perl=TRUE`;
- `(?<=name)[^;]*` find all non-`;` text after `name`
- `regmatches(a, gre)` returns the values; we don't need to run this line of code for anything other than validation of the text that will be removed;
- `` `regmatches<-` `` is a form of `regmatches` for the LHS of an assignment operator (not all functions have this form); we use this to replace the matched portions.

Comment: is it possible to do it with gsub?

Comment: Yup, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

With `gsub` and `perl=TRUE`:

```
> gsub("(?<=name).*", "", unlist(strsplit(a, ";")), perl=TRUE)
[1] "My name" "My name" "My name"
>
```

Explanation:

This detects `name` in a lookbehind and removes everything (`.*`) after it. First of all it uses `strsplit` to split it into a list by `;`, then I use `unlist` to make it a vector.

Use:

```
> paste(gsub("(?<=name).*", "", unlist(strsplit(a, ";")), perl=TRUE), collapse=";")
[1] "My name;My name;My name"
>
```

Comment: that's not the expected outpout, it's : "My name;My name;My name;"

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this

`gsub("My name[^;]*","My name",a)`

Comment: This is replacing it with `My name`, I say this isn't optimal, look at my solution or r2evans edit

Comment: you´re right, now it works fine, but isn't optimal as yours @r2evans